# I need help finding the correct html tag for headline links url my web scraper. The purpose of of my scraper is to scrape headlines, stories ,links

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

When I run the scraper the output on my Django home page is okay but the url displays an error message 404 and other articles showing I am using the wrong tag **https://www.coindesk.com/news/tag/crypto-lending** the correct link url is **https://www.coindesk.com/news/tag/crypto-lending**. The correct tag with the link is <a title =xxxxxx href<. How do I write this tag

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

crypto_headlines = []


def crypto_news():
    """ user agent to facilitates end-user interaction with web content"""

    headers = {
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36'
    }

    base_url ='https://www.coindesk.com/news'

    source = requests.get(base_url).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")       
    
    
    articles = soup.find_all(class_ = 'text-content')
    
    #print(len(articles))
    #print(articles) 

    
    for article in articles:
        
        try:
    
            headline = article.h4.text.strip()
            text = article.find(class_="card-text").text.strip()
            link = base_url + article.a['href']
            #img_url = base_url + article.image_src['src']

            crypto_dict = {}

            crypto_dict['Headline']= headline
            crypto_dict['Text'] = text
            crypto_dict['Link']= link


            crypto_headlines.append(crypto_dict)
        except AttributeError as ex:
            print('Error:', ex)

    print(crypto_headlines)

crypto_news()
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking for, your given code is clearly working and crypto-lending page is clearly saying that there is no page like that!

Comment: link tag does not display the headlines compare the link url from the website and the output from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scraping from wrong `<a>`, you are scraping from first `<a>` but needed link is in 2nd `<a>`.

Here's the code

```
link = base_url + article.find_all("a")[1]["href"]
```

Just changing this line should solve your problem!